Mermaid - How can I change the "TEXT SIZE" of "LINK TEXT"
I want to be able to make the "link" text size DIFFERENT than the standard text size of the document.
Take this flowchart as the example:
flowchart LR

01(Server01)
02(Server02)
03(Server03)

01 -- TCP (443) --> 02
02 -- TCP (443) --> 03

I understand I can change the color and background of the LINK TEXT fairly easily by doing something like this at the end of the code.  I can't find a way to get the text to display smaller than the standard text of the document. Does anyone know if I can maybe use some CSS or something else to get it to change. If so.. how would you do that?
flowchart LR

01(Server01)
02(Server02)
03(Server03)

01 -- TCP (443) --> 02
02 -- TCP (443) --> 03

linkStyle 0 stroke:blue,stroke-width:2px,color:red,size:5;

Any help would be really appreciated.
linkStyle 0 stroke:blue,stroke-width:2px,color:red,size:5;
There doesn't seem to be a way to change the size.

Replace size: 5 with font-size: 5pt, for example.
